# Auto forms with GET requests won't get filled out when run in Docker

Tags: selenium, docker, protractor

I have Protractor tests that fills out few forms. Everything works fine when running tests outside the docker. I have a form, in which some fields will be automatically filled out when specific ID`s will be used. Running outside docker using bellow function

```
await element.sendkeys("ID");
```

ID is entered then, I click on a different element, so GET request would be made, and form would be filled out. This does not happen when tests are run in Docker. "ID" gets entered, but the form is not filled out.

I am now assuming that it must be Docker's fault, but do not know where to start.

I am using headless Chrome.

Edit: It seems that it`s not a basic input field, but GET/POST field, is there any difference how one should enter data in those fields?

Comment: Do you also use headless chrome when testing locally?

Comment: Yes. It was also fine when tested locally with headless chrome.